# Justify CSS text and increase space between characters

Tags: html, css

I request your help because I have a problem because I need to `css`, justify the text and in addition to this the text inside the div must occupy all the contents of `div` without leaving blank spaces, if it is possible that the spaces between the characters grow to occupy all the contents of the `div`, something very similar as `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;`

The desired result is that the text occupies all the `div` if you leave any space, please look at the last line, it should be adjusted by spaces between characters to fill the box. The line that is blue does not have any relevance.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> InfoShop </title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @page {
      margin-left: 25pt;
      margin-top: 15pt;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 6pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
    }
    
    .Arial05 {
      font: 5pt Arial
    }
    
    .Arial07 {
      font: 7pt Arial
    }
    
    div {
      text-align: justify;
      text-justify: inter-word;
    }
    
    a {
      color: blue;
      font: 6pt Arial
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="730" align="CENTER" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
          <font class="Arial05">
            <a title="Additional text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque a harum ducimus fugiat aspernatur
                                        vero alias dolorem maiores, sapiente odit itaque. Cupiditate quod laboriosam nemo fugit minima
                                        minus suscipit necessitatibus. </a>
          </font>
          <font class="Arial07">
            <div>
              Lorem ipsum pain sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque a harum ducimus fugiat aspernatur vero aka dolorem maiores, sapiente odit itaque. Cupiditate quod laboriosam nemo fugit minima minus suscipit necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
              adipisicing elit. Eaque a harum ducimus fugiat aspernatur vero aka dolorem maiores, sapiente odit itaque. Cupiditate quod laboriosam nemo fugit minima minus suscipit necessitatibus. Lorem ipsum pain sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
              Eaque a harum ducimus fugiat aspernatur vero aka dolorem maiores, sapiente odit itaque. Cupiditate quod laboriosam nemo fugit
            </div>
          </font>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<font>` element doesn't exist anymore

Comment: I know how to do this by separating the words, but by characters ... i do not think it is possible with just css

Comment: Are you aware of this css prop? `letter-spacing: normal|length|initial|inherit;`

Comment: @j08691 I can not change the label. This HTML is consumed from a web, therefore I should keep it the same

Comment: @ I. R. R. The problem is that this information is dynamic, and how could you determine how much space would be needed between characters ...?

Comment: The text-justify property specifies the justification method of text when text-align is set to "justify". 

    `text-align: justify;`
   ` text-justify: inter-word;`

for letting spacing, you can use `px` or `rem`, etc. 

    `letter-spacing: normal|length|initial|inherit;` or
    `letter-spacing: 3px/0.5rem;`